# touchesBegan syntax error - has no member

Tags: ios, swift

Essentially what I am looking to do is to test if the user is clicking on the *left* or *right* side of the screen. So far I've had no trouble with this code in the past. However, with the Swift 4 update it gives me some problems with the syntax. I've solved most of the issues however.

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch:UITouch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch
    let touchLocation = touch.location(in: self) 
    if touchLocation.x < self.frame.size.width / 2 {
        // Left side of the screen
        print("Left")
    } else {
        // Right side of the screen
        print("Right")
    }
}
```

This one line I haven't been able to fix yet.

```
let touch:UITouch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch
```

The error message it's giving me is:

> Value of type 'Set<UITouch>' has no member 'anyObject'

Comment: There is no such thing as Swift 10

Comment: You're correct. I mixed up Xcode version number with the code version. :)

Comment: Your question title is extremely... southing. Why put 2019 in it? What happened with the new year? And absolutely, if your claim is something related to Swift 4 (previously Swift 10), can you please state if it's Swift 4.0/4.1 or Swift 4.2? Everyone who has used Swift begins reading this as though you aren't addressing what really is your issue. (And if it **is** related to Swift 4 versus some earlier version, why do you think that?)

Comment: Stack overflow doesn't allow you to put a title that is too similar to any others, even if it doesn't Relate to the Same Question. Which is why I had to mix it up my friend. btw, I appreciate your title change. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
guard let touch = touches.first else { return }
```